# ASP.NET MVC 4 : how to create a "good" Model?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm building a website using ASP.net MVC 4. This website will be used by its users to handle their meetings.

With the model below, if I create a controller with Entity Framework, Visual Studio generates a CRUD where every attribute is editable (except `MeetingId`, the key) : `Begin`, `End`, `Message`, `IsSent`, `CustomerId` and `UserId`.

Problems :

- where can I forbid the user to modify the `IsSent` attribute ?
- where can I link `CustomerId` (as a foreign key) to the `Customer` table ? So the user can select the right Customer from a list ?
- where can I link `UserId` (as a foreign key) to the user curently creating the `meeting` ?

Thanks

```
[Table("Meeting")]
public class MeetingModel
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int MeetingId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime Begin { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime End { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public bool IsSent { get; set; }

    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I strongly recommend you to go through this http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc

it will learn you all that you want to know about relations in EF.

Comment: good model... good designer  ,good designer...lots of homework. I spent 6 mths researching when transitioning from SAP to .net.  Im curious when people think its trivial. How much time do you plan to spend designing the solution ?  What do you understand by good ?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not easy to answer because here is many ways to do that.

Model is representation of your data in storage so model is not responsible for your business rules. That is why you should use model just to manipulate with data but any way you can add validation to your model.

> where can I forbid the user to modify the IsSent attribute ?

First, you should do that in controller there you can check user role and show this property on form or not depends on user permissions.
Second you can separate Database Models from ViewModel so for example in your example it will be db model and then you can add two other models such as AdminMeetingModel, RestrictedUserMeetingModel.

> where can I link CustomerId (as a foreign key) to the Customer table ?
>   So the user can select the right Customer from a list ?
>   I am not sure about your mvc level, but its easy to do in View 
>   @Html.DropDownFor(m=>m.CustomerId, LIST_OF_CUSTOMERS)
>   Then in controller you should do next

```
public ActionResult Save(MeetingModel model)
```

And MVC will do job for you.

> where can I link UserId (as a foreign key) to the user curently
>   creating the meeting ?

Same here you can do it in controller or if you decide use custom models then in constructor you can set UserID = SomeMethodWhichGetUserId()